# @MockBean test for kotlin app not working

Tags: spring, kotlin, mocking

i have a seemingly very simple use case where i want to mock a spring bean. I have tried a few things, but no luck. Below is simplest version of code where i get the error:

```
io.mockk.MockKException: Failed matching mocking signature for

left matchers: [any(), any(), eq(foo-topic)]
```

```
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.mockk
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension
import org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture


@ActiveProfiles("integration-test")
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = [PubsubApplication::class],
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
)
@ExtendWith(value = [SpringExtension::class])
class PubsubApplicationIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var helloController: HelloController

    @MockBean
    lateinit var pubSubProducerTracerV2: PubSubProducerTracerV2

    val future: ListenableFuture<String> = mockk()

    @Test
    fun `publish and consume with tracing`() {

        every {
            pubSubProducerTracerV2.publish(
                publisher = any(),
                topic = eq("foo-topic"),
                payload = any()
            )
        } returns future

        helloController.helloPubSubTracing("damo")
    }
}
```

If i rewrite my code to use org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers, i get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: any() must not be null

    at PubsubApplicationIntegrationTest.publish and consume with tracing(PubsubApplicationIntegrationTest.kt:40)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
    Suppressed: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:

-> at PubsubApplicationIntegrationTest.publish and consume with tracing(PubsubApplicationIntegrationTest.kt:40)

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object 
like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
use primitive alternatives.
    when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
    when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.

        at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:83)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:70)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:64)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:441)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.afterEach(SpringExtension.java:206)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterEachCallbacks$11(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:253)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$12(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:269)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$13(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:269)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:268)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAfterEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:252)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
        ... 43 more
```

```
import io.mockk.mockk
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString
import org.mockito.Mockito.`when`
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension
import org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture


@ActiveProfiles("integration-test")
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = [PubsubApplication::class],
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
)
@ExtendWith(value = [SpringExtension::class])
class PubsubApplicationIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var helloController: HelloController

    @MockBean(name = "pubSubProducerTracerV2")
    lateinit var pubSubProducerTracerV2: PubSubProducerTracerV2

    val future: ListenableFuture<String> = mockk()

    @Test
    fun `publish and consume with tracing`() {

        `when`(
            pubSubProducerTracerV2.publish(
                publisher = any(),
                topic = anyString(),
                payload = any()
            )
        ).thenReturn(future)

        helloController.helloPubSubTracing("damo")
    }
}
```

Sticking a debugger in, i can see pubSubProducerTracerV2 is being mocked, so that part seems to be working.

Any tips appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Using the matches provided by this dependency works..                                                                       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-kotlin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>